# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wifi not connecting when I am a few distance away from modem

Tags: networking, 16.04, broadcom

I'm having strange issue on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.If I stand near modem i am able to connect to internet but if i walk a little away, even though wifi signal shown strong, i can only get a slow connection/no connectivity at all.If i walk back to the modem, it started working again.Sometimes it worked for 3 or four hours away from modem and started giving trouble again.Same worked on windows 10 very well(unfortunately i am locked out of windows 10 and using ubuntu in dual boot mode,with security disabled).

Using HP Pavilion with Broadcom NIC. Any help/solution?

`lspci -nn -d 14e4` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

**SOLVED:** I bought EUDP mini usb ethernet adapter, that is working well with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Facing same issue in mobile or in any other device?

Comment: No, wi-fi is working fine on mobile away from modem but at same distance my laptop not able to connect(now I am away from modem at desk and able to access very slow internet).

Comment: Is seems like an issue with the laptop wifi receiver and not about the drivers. If it is an issue with the wifi driver or os you wouldn't able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to interference in the signal.  Try reconfiguring your modem to use a different wifi channel (ideally, check for available channels or scan for what channels other networks in your location are using -- and avoid them).

Comment: Same wifi worked with windows and working with my mobile.Even on laptop working sometimes and after few hours it stopped working.If you still suggest changing Channel, i need to look at how to do that. I am not much experienced with that stuff.

Comment: Different OS (Windows, Ubuntu, iOS or Android) have different levels of tolerance for connection quality.  I'd still recommend trying a channel scan/switch.

Comment: This is due to some versions of broadcom NIC not having support. I tried different ways, used it for quite sometime with very uncertain connectivity. At the end installed windows as NIC working without issues on Windows.  As i didn't try your suggestion I cannot accept this as answer.

Comment: If the NIC hardware you have isn't supported, this wouldn't have solved the problem, so shouldn't be accepted.  Generally, if I have a choice, I avoid Broadcomm hardware -- none of them are fully supported in any flavor of Linux.